# VBA-Split doesn't split on space basis

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am a total newbie in VBA. I would parse a text file with the following format:

```
040 11  VAR1    TRUE
040 12  VAR2    FALSE
040 13  VAR3    FALSE
040 14  VAR4    FALSE
```

and I used the code:

```
Sub Bouton4_Cliquer()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String

myFile = "C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\textlist.txt"
Open myFile For Input As #1

Dim Result() As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
Do Until EOF(1)
    i = i + 1
    Line Input #1, textline
    Result() = Split(textline)

    Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 1).value = Result(2)
    Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 2).value = Result(1)
    Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 3).value = Result(0)
    Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 4).value = Result(3)
Loop

Close #1
End Sub
```

Which returns me an error cause the `Result()` have only one element.

In fact, I noticed Split puts the whole line in a single element, without splitting it on space basis.

Comment: Try `Result() = Split(textline, " ")`

Comment: tried, same error

Comment: Please show us what `textline` holds before parsing.

Comment: I tried and it works.

Comment: oh well... has no space... how is it possible?! The txt clearly has spaces

Comment: Maybe try copying the Character from Text file and Put it in `" "` in the above line

Comment: ok if I paste it raw, it is copied with right spacing

Comment: Is your text not delimiter through a horizontal tab? My guess is you could try `Split(textline, Chr(9))`

Comment: you were right, it seems they were tab and not spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change:**

```
Result() = Split(textline)
```

**With:**

```
Result() = Split(textline, Chr(9))' Tab or any other character that you want to use as delimiter
```

`Split` takes another argument as Basis on which to split.

Also Note that, if your data have more than a Single space in between two words, then the way you are printing the data will not print all the Elements. I would suggest you to use 
`Lbound(Result) to Ubound(Result)`

Comment: Yes, changing it to Char(9) as you identified it correctly.

Comment: Yes, better :). Also see that the way OP want's to print elements won't work going from Lbound to Ubound. In fact, because his data is tab-delimited, my guess is that it's automated data which will be fine, the way he used it. That's just my guess.

Comment: In any case, it's better to use `Lbound to Ubound` in my opinion, you never know when the data can have 2 Tabs.

Comment: @Mikki hence processing the input like in my answer. I've still got a check in there for the size of array. But, I've converted all `vbTab` (`Chr(9)`) into spaces then used the trim function to remove any double spacing before splitting the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your input up before using the `Split` function. The following will replaced any tabbed characters with a space and remove any double or more spacing

```
Sub Bouton4_Cliquer()
    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String

    myFile = "C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\textlist.txt"
    Open myFile For Input As #1

    Dim Result() As String
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        i = i + 1
        Line Input #1, textline

        ' This will remove any tabbed characters and replace with spaces and remove any non-single spacing between words
        textline = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(textline, Chr(9), " "))

        Result() = Split(textline)

        ' Test if array is correct size, if not print to Immediate Window
        If UBound(Result) - LBound(Result) + 1 <> 4 Then Debug.Print "Error with line:", Join(textline, ";")

        Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 1).Value = Result(2)
        Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 2).Value = Result(1)
        Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 3).Value = Result(0)
        Worksheets("BOOLEAN").Cells(i, 4).Value = Result(3)
    Loop

    Close #1
End Sub
```

N.B - Have removed `vbTab` from my original answer as it is equivalent to `Chr(9)`